# Does every integer polynomial evaluate to infinitely many composite numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and suppose $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$ where $a_n > 0$ and $a_0 \in \{-1, +1\}$. Is there for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ an integer $m> n$ such that $f(m)$ is (positive and) composite?

Comment: You are using here $n$ with two different meanings, or am I wrong?

Comment: I downvoted because I think that this problem is really too easy for MO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Choose $n_0$ large, so the polynomial is always positive, and let $k = f(n_0)$. Then choose $n = n_0 + ik$ for $i$ large; we have that $f(n)$ is congruent to $f(n_0)$ mod $k$, so as long as $i$ is large enough, $f(n)$ is composite.